# Convert multi if-else to simple Lambda expression code in java

Tags: java, lambda

I'm new with Lambda and I want to convert my simple code that has to many if-else into Lambda code.
Can anyone explain me how to do it? I don't really understand how to build it

```
public void registerModule(HttpServletRequest req, ModuleType moduleType) {
    LOGGER.debug("Register New Module - " + moduleType.name());
    ModuleEntityGenerator moduleEntityGenerator = new ModuleEntityGenerator();
    try {
        if (!req.getParts().isEmpty() && !req.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
            ModuleEntityDao moduleEntityDao = moduleEntityGenerator.get(req, moduleType);
            if (moduleEntityDao != null) {
                if (processRegistryDal.getModule(moduleType, moduleEntityDao.getId()) == null) { // Check BA is not already exist
                    processRegistryDal.addNewModule(moduleEntityDao);
                } else { // If already exists just update the current row
                    processRegistryDal.updateModule(moduleEntityDao);
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("The BA object is null. There is nothing to register");
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("The rest request is empty.No info to register");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IO Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Servlet Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would extract methods first before trying lambdas.

Comment: Why do you believe using lambda would improve the code? It won't.

Comment: I won't be easier with lambda, don't think that

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with lambda here, just a quick cleanup tip.  Early `return`s are a great way to flatten code, to make its apparent complexity more closely match its actual complexity.  Just invert the sense of your `if` conditions, pull up the error log, and return.  Look how much better this one transformation makes your code.

```
public void registerModule(HttpServletRequest req, ModuleType moduleType) {
    LOGGER.debug("Register New Module - " + moduleType.name());
    try {
        if (req.getParts().isEmpty() || req.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.error("The rest request is empty.No info to register");
            return;
        }

        ModuleEntityGenerator moduleEntityGenerator = new ModuleEntityGenerator();
        ModuleEntityDao moduleEntityDao = moduleEntityGenerator.get(req, moduleType);
        if (moduleEntityDao == null) {
          LOGGER.error("The BA object is null. There is nothing to register");
          return;
        }

        if (processRegistryDal.getModule(moduleType, moduleEntityDao.getId()) == null) { // Check BA is not already exist
            processRegistryDal.addNewModule(moduleEntityDao);
        } else { // If already exists just update the current row
            processRegistryDal.updateModule(moduleEntityDao);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IO Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Servlet Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply re-organize your code, you wouldn't get so many nested `if` statements.

E.g. reverse the conditions. Instead of:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        // code here
    } else {
        // ERROR
    }
} else {
    // ERROR
}
```

Turn it around and use `else-if` constructs:

```
if (! a) {
    // ERROR
} else if (! b) {
    // ERROR
} else {
    // code here
}
```

A side-benefit is that the short "ERROR" logic is dealt with right next to the `if` condition, instead of appearing somewhere a lot further down, which had the condition and the action separated too far apart.

With your code, it can be simplified like this:

```
public void registerModule(HttpServletRequest req, ModuleType moduleType) {
    LOGGER.debug("Register New Module - " + moduleType.name());
    try {
        ModuleEntityDao moduleEntityDao;
        if (req.getParts().isEmpty() || req.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.error("The rest request is empty.No info to register");
        } else if ((moduleEntityDao = new ModuleEntityGenerator().get(req, moduleType)) == null) {
            LOGGER.error("The BA object is null. There is nothing to register");
        } else if (processRegistryDal.getModule(moduleType, moduleEntityDao.getId()) == null) { // Check BA is not already exist
            processRegistryDal.addNewModule(moduleEntityDao);
        } else { // If already exists just update the current row
            processRegistryDal.updateModule(moduleEntityDao);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IO Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Servlet Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about to split each `if` into separate method with low scope.

Main method look very simple.

```
public void registerModule(HttpServletRequest req, ModuleType moduleType) {
    LOGGER.debug("Register New Module - " + moduleType.name());

    try {
        if (!isRequestEmpty(req))
            addOrUpdateModule(createModule(req, moduleType));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IO Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Servlet Error\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

Helper methods. In case developer need details, look at it.

```
private static boolean isRequestEmpty(HttpServletRequest req) {
    if (req.getParts().isEmpty() || req.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.error("The rest request is empty.No info to register");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static ModuleEntityDao createModule(HttpServletRequest req, ModuleType moduleType) {
    ModuleEntityDao module = new ModuleEntityGenerator().get(req, moduleType);

    if (module != null)
        return module;

    LOGGER.error("The BA object is null. There is nothing to register");
    return module;
}

private void addOrUpdateModule(ModuleEntityDao module) {
    if(module == null)
        return;

    if(processRegistryDal.getModule(module.getModuleType(), module.getId()) == null)
        processRegistryDal.addNewModule(moduleEntityDao);
    else
        processRegistryDal.updateModule(moduleEntityDao);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not lamda, but makes it easy to read the program with the principle of immediately leaving the function if the input is not valid by calling "return".

```
if (a != null && b != null) {
   // c
}
else {
   // d
}
```

to

```
if (a == null || b == null) {
   // d
   return;
}

// c
```

Example

```
public void registerModule(HttpServletRequest req, ModuleType moduleType) {
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("Register New Module - " + moduleType.name());
        ModuleEntityGenerator moduleEntityGenerator = new ModuleEntityGenerator();

        if (req.getParts().isEmpty() || req.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.error("The rest request is empty.No info to register");
            return;
        }

        ModuleEntityDao moduleEntityDao = moduleEntityGenerator.get(req, moduleType);
        if (moduleEntityDao == null) {
            LOGGER.error("The BA object is null. There is nothing to register");
            return;
        }     

        if (processRegistryDal.getModule(moduleType, moduleEntityDao.getId()) == null) { 
            // Check BA is not already exist
            processRegistryDal.addNewModule(moduleEntityDao);
            return;
        }

        // If already exists just update the current row
        processRegistryDal.updateModule(moduleEntityDao);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```